# What other approch I can use to select * while inner joining multiple tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

I want to create View by selecting all data from multiple tables, but the error I got saying that I have duplicate columns

```
CREATE VIEW All_Data AS
SELECT *
FROM table1 tb1
    INNER JOIN table 2 tb2 ON tb1.ID = tb2.ID
    INNER JOIN table 3 tb3 ON tb2.ID = tb3.ID
    INNER JOIN table 4 tb4 ON tb3.ID = tb4.ID
    INNER JOIN table 5 tb5 ON tb4.ID = tb5.ID
    INNER JOIN table 6 tb6 ON o.SpecialID = tb6.ID
    INNER JOIN table 7 tb7 ON tb6.ID = tb7.ID
    LEFT JOIN table 8 tb8 ON tb7.ID = tb8.ID
```

However, I am still having the same problem. I want to know is there a faster way to do that instead using alias selecting each column one by one.

Comment: Pay attention the the mouseover of the `oracle` tag. Its probably not what's intented. Welcome to SO. There is also https://dba.stackexchange.com for pure database questoins

Comment: Name (and properly qualify) the columns. Simples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DISTINCT` won't help as its talking about duplicate columns vs duplicate rows.

Its the `*` that is causing the columns from all tables, with duplicate column names to be returned. You'll need to replace the `*` with explicit columns and alias them like below if both are needed.

```
SELECT p.created_date as product_created_date, order.created_date as order_created date .....
```

Note using a view isn't a needed pattern. Selects of exactly the right result are normally sufficient. Selects on views can suffer in performance as they are more complicated for MySQL to optimize. They are useful if you need an explicit `GRANT` on the them for a specific user however.

Comment: I know, but I have so many columns, and I need all of them

Comment: Sure its one of the downsides of having identical column names. Sorry no easy answer. Consistent capitalization will help you write queries later. Recommend fixing before there's too much code.

Comment: I eventually pick all the columns one by one and use alias. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the full list of columns that you want to be part of the view. There is no shortcut.

But yes, to ease your work, If you want the comma separated list of the column names of the table then you can use the following query for each table and put their columns in your select query. You will then just need to alias the columns which have same names.

```
Select listagg('pd.'|| column_name, ',')
         Within group (order by column_id)
  From user_tab_columns
 Where table_name = 'your_table_name_in_capital';
```

Note that you need to replace `'pd.'` for each table with the table alias in your query.